# How to striptags in haystack highlight?

Tags: django, django-haystack

I am using django-haystack. In the highlight haystack provides, how can i render tags or striptags in the result.

```
               {% for text in result.highlighted.text %}
                    <blockquote>{% highlight text with query %}</blockquote>
               {% endfor %}
```

I need to do something like this:

```
           {% for text in result.highlighted.text %}
                <blockquote>{% highlight text|striptags with query %}</blockquote>
           {% endfor %}
```

But this is not working, please suggest something.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
{% for text in result.highlighted.text %}
    <blockquote>
        {% with text|striptags as stripped_text %}
            {% highlight stripped_text with query %}
        {% endwith %}
    </blockquote>
{% endfor %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/def/ref/templates/builtins/#with